# Using Django's get_form_kwargs to modify form.exclude[]?

Tags: python, django, forms, keyword-argument

One of my models has some options that will control the way it's form is displayed.  For example automatically generating customer IDs.  Right now I have 2 different forms defined which are exactly the same except for the exclude list, which itself is only different for the customer ID field.

I thought I could use get_form_kwargs to modify that, but it doesn't appear to be working that way.

Is there any way to make that happen or am I stuck with separate forms?  Not very DRY.

---

**get_form_kwargs**

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CustomerCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()

    if not self.request.user.company.generate_account_numbers:
        kwargs['exclude'].extend('customer_id')
    return kwargs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exclude` option is used by the `metaclass` to prevent that certain model fields are generated as form fields *during class definition*. Changing it after the class has been defined has no effect.

`get_form_kwargs` provides the arguments for instantiating the form instance. By definition, the class has been defined before the form kwargs are ever provided, so changing `exclude` in the form kwargs has no effect.

A workaround is to override the `__init__` method and manually remove the already-generated `customer_id` field if a certain parameter is passed.

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclude_customer_id = kwargs.pop(exclude_customer_id, False):
        super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if exclude_customer_id:
            del self.fields['customer_id']
```

You must decide if the extra `__init__` code is worth it to avoid having two form classes.

Comment: Wow. That worked surprisingly well.  A few minor tweaks to your snippet and it's running.  Thanks!